# Runaway potential in cosmology inflation

Tags: cosmology, potential, cosmological-inflation

I'm looking for a review articles that explaining the issues with runaway potential in cosmology inflation, when a potential has a hilltop and then it goes to zero at infinity. I read somewhere that that if the universe start at a big bang (r->inf) and the expansion start climbing the potential to the hilltop ( if it has sufficient initial condition that larger then the value of the top of the potential), it will site on the top for ever. is some one can explain to me how it works without solving the H R equation?
Also if there is a good review articles that i can read on the subject

Comment: In the model of inflation to which you refer, the field starts out on the hilltop and this causes the universe to inflate.  Eventually, a thermal or quantum fluctuation kicks the field off the top, and it rolls down.  The universe continues to inflate.  Eventually, as the field gains sufficient speed, the universe stops inflating.  There are no "issues" with "runaway" potentials as you describe; the field just asymptotes to infinity.  These models are not traditional; typically there is a (meta)stable vacuum that attracts the field after inflation ends.

Comment: Thank u. i just want to fully understand.  I have a potential similar to F(R) = R-w/R where the solution at R=infinity start at h=0 and then climb quickly to the top of of the potential, so without any quantum or thermal fluctuations, it will just seat there and will not continue to drop to the other side where R=0

Comment: What is R, h, and w? Why is the field climbing the potential in violation of energy conditions? Why is it not affected by fluctuations?

Comment: F(R) cosmology with minimum coupling, R is the Ricci curvature,h is the expansion function that i'm trying to solve as function of R in the expansion equation, w is just a constant. I was just looking in the classical view. I also was trying to numerically solve the equation, but what i get is that any initial condition for h (at very large R) does not really matter, the h end up on the top of the potential.